# some question of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes and let $F$ be a sheaf on $Y$.
Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphisme of schemes.
Define the inverse image of $F$,
$$f^*F:= f^{-1}F\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}Y}\mathcal{O}_X$$

For an open subset $U\subseteq X$, $f$ be the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow X$
and $F$ be a sheaf on $X$. 
Then is it true that $f^*F=F|_{U}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, since in this case the structural map $f^{-1} \mathcal{O} _{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{O} _{U}$ is an isomorphism, because the functors $f^{-1}(-)$ and $(-) |_{U}$ coincide (essentially by definition) and $\mathcal{O} _{U} = \mathcal{O} _{X} |_{U}$. So you actually have

> $f^{*} \mathcal{F} = f^{-1}\mathcal{F} \otimes _{f^{-1} \mathcal{O} _{X}} \mathcal{O} _{U} \simeq f^{-1}\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F} |_{U}$

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make any sense for two reasons: The definition of $f^* F$ as a tensor product makes only sense when $F$ is a sheaf of modules on $Y$, not just a sheaf. And $f^* F|_U$ doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you mean $f^* F$ and you want to prove that $f^* F \cong F|_U$? Of course it is not important that $X,Y$ are schemes, all this works for arbitrary ringed spaces.

The most important property of $f^*$ (and in fact, from a more abstract point of view, this is the *definition*) is that it is left adjoint to $f_*$ (both for categories of sheaves, as well as for categories of sheaves of modules). If $f$ is the inclusion of an open subspace $U \hookrightarrow X$, then one can verify directly that $(-)|_U$ is left adjoint to $f_*$, since there is a canonical bijection $\hom(F|_U,G) \cong \hom(F,f_* G)$ given by $\alpha \mapsto (V \mapsto \alpha(V \cap U))$. It follows that $f^* \cong (-)|_U$.

The explicit construction of $f^*$ is not really important, you can always derive anything from its universal property.

Comment: It is a safe bet that «a sheaf» in the question means «a sheaf of modules»...

Comment: Of course I agree, otherwise the formula for $f^*$ doesn't make sense, you don't have to teach me ;).

Comment: I wasn't teaching you: I was observing that your first paragraph is probably a lost fight against a standard *abus de language*! And as such, I'd suggest really going for «sheaf of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules», to remove any possibility that we might be referring to modules over another sheaf of algebras on $Y$! :-)